# In a shell script, How to give a variable another value after one job is done?

Tags: shell, shell-script, zip, variable

I'm trying to make a script which will see if the directory exists and will zip all of its contents under it according to the name/path of the directory.

The farthest I could go was -

```
#!/system/bin/sh -xv

Z="$PWD/../WorkingDir";
T='320';
F='480';
I='540';
D='dark';
L='light';
P='play';

cd $Z;

if [ -d $T/$D ]; then
    R=""$T"_"$D".zip";
else
    if [ -d $T/$L ]; then
        R=""$T"_"$L".zip";
    else
        R="file.zip";
    fi
fi;

for dir in */*/; do
    #Skip directories where the zip already exists
    [ -e "$dir"/"$R" ] || 
    ( cd -- "$dir" && zip -0rq "$R" .)
done
```

**But this happens -**

```
#!/system/bin/sh -xv
...
.
.
if [ -d $T/$D ]; then
    R=""$T"_"$D".zip";
else
    if [ -d $T/$L ]; then
        R=""$T"_"$L".zip";
    else
        R="file.zip";
    fi
fi;
+ [ -d 320/dark ]
+ R=320_dark.zip

for dir in */*/; do
    #Skip directories where the zip already exists
    [ -e "$dir"/"$R" ] ||
    ( cd -- "$dir" && zip -0rq "$R" .)
done
+ [ -e 320/dark//320_dark.zip ]
+ cd -- 320/dark/
+ zip -0rq 320_dark.zip .
+ [ -e 320/light//320_dark.zip ]
+ cd -- 320/light/
+ zip -0rq 320_dark.zip .
.
.
...and so on..
```

Every file gets named the same (*320_dark.zip* in this case). I want it different (according to the folder name/path) for every file that gets zipped.

I wanted -

```
+ [ -d 320/dark ]
+ R=320_dark.zip
```

-to change every time for every folder. Like it should be `320_light.zip` for the folder path `320/light`.

**So the last part of the output would be -**

```
+ [ -e 320/dark//320_dark.zip ]
+ cd -- 320/dark/
+ zip -0rq 320_dark.zip .
+ [ -e 320/light//320_light.zip ]
+ cd -- 320/light/
+ zip -0rq 320_light.zip .
```

Comment: Your script sets the ZIP archive file name *before* entering the `for` loop, consequently all compressed files will have that very same name. Could you add examples of what you'd wished?

Comment: @Nasha I've edited the question. Please check now.

Comment: Not an answer, but you definitely should try to use more verbose variable names. Single character names are only a recipe for disaster

Comment: @cremefraiche Yes I get you, but that's working too. So I'm not quite bothered about that.

Comment: @cremefraiche : it makes no difference whether `//` or `/` as shells properly eliminate the dupe slash evaluating expressions.

Comment: @Nasha fair enough

Comment: @chinmay-kunkikar what looks weird to me is `cd -- "$dir" && zip -0rq "$R" .`, which means `zip` will also include its temporary archive while zipping the current directory as you don't specify an absolute path for the archive. You seem to create a ZIP archive in the same (current) directory as the one you compress. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion, removing single-letter variables and changing the location of the archive for consistency's sake:

```
#!/system/bin/sh -xv

cd "$PWD/../WorkingDir"

compress() {
    # Detect only known dir names, convert slash to underscore
    local arch="$(echo $1 | sed -rne '/320\/(light|dark)/s@/@_@gp')"

    # Set a default value to the variable
    : ${arch:=file}

    # Only create a ZIP archive if not present in the parent directory
    # Note $PWD is evaluated *before* cd
    [ -f "${arch}.zip" ] || ( cd -- $1 && zip -0rq "${PWD}/${arch}.zip ." )
}

for dir in */*/; do
    compress $dir
done
```

Just change the `sed` line to add what I called "well-known directory names".

---

**EDIT**: Adding a few explanations, as per OP request.

The script does verify conditions prior to zipping directories each time a new directory is found by the `for` loop. Variables have also been eliminated. Let's dissect the code.

### The main loop

```
cd "$PWD/../WorkingDir"

for dir in */*/; do     # Ensures to select only directories
    compress $dir       # compress runs some checks prior to compressing
done
```

There is indeed not much more to say about it.

### The `compress` routine

```
local arch="$(echo $1 | sed -rne '/320\/(light|dark)/s@/@_@gp')"
```

`$1` is the argument passed to `compressed`, i.e. the directory to check and compress. What `sed` does first (`'/320\/(light|dark)/'`) is check whether the path is of the form

```
320/light
320/dark
```

and returns the path with the slash converted to an underscore: `'s@/@_@g'`. Using the at sign as a separator for readability to avoid escaping the slash. Other valid notations are `'s:/:_:g'` or `'s#/#_#g'` or the classical `'s/\//_/g'`. Note how the slash to transform is escaped with an anti slash. I find the latter form less readable though.

The trailing `p` works together with `sed -n`; the latter option in this particular case means «*don't echo anything unless told to by `p` whenever a match (i.e. in the enclosing slashes) is found*». Therefore `arch` will contain a path with the slash transformed into an underscore *if and only if* the regular expression `320\/(light|dark)` is found in the path. Otherwise it will echo nothing, making `arch` a blank variable.

Option `-r` is a convenient way to tell `sed` to use canonical regular expressions, more readable. Otherwise you would need to escape the parenthesis and pipe characters. I find `'/320\/(light|dark)/s@/@_@gp'` more readable than `'/320\/\(light\|dark\)/s@/@_@gp'` or `'/320\/\(light\|dark\)/s/\//_/gp'`.

```
: ${arch:=file}
```

This line sets `arch` to its default value "file" if it is blank. The weird construction is required because `${arch:=file}` alone triggers a syntax error. The colon tells the shell to do nothing (`:`) but assign `arch` a value if it is blank.

```
    [ -f "${arch}.zip" ] || ( cd -- $1 && zip -0rq "${PWD}/${arch}.zip ." )
```

Here I used `-f` instead of `-e` because the former also checks for zero-length files. The test will succeed only if a ZIP archive exists *and* has a non zero length.

If there's no archive file in the parent (or the script's *current*) directory or if its size is null, then the script spawns a sub-shell that changes to the directory passed as an argument to `compress` and zips its content. Note that variables `$1` and `$PWD` are evaluated *before* the sub-shell executes its instructions, i.e. `$PWD` is equal to the parent directory `$Z` in your initial version.

### Expanding the filter

You can act upon `sed` the following way:

```
sed -rne '/320\/(light|dark|play)/s@/@_@gp'
```

to check directory names such as

```
320/light
320/dark
320/play
```

You may also consider `/(320|480|540)\/(light|dark|play)/`, which gives you 9 combinations, or a more generic form `/[0-9]+\/(light|dark|play)/` (any number followed by a slash and one of "*light*", "*dark*" and "*play*") or even `/[0-9]+\/\w+/` (any number followed by a slash and a word aka `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`). It all depends how strict or broad you want the filter to be.

Comment: I was trying to stick with OPs theme, but I like your solution more.

Comment: Wow! Seems quite promising. I would love to do it as soon as possible, but it'll take me some more time to understand and actually work on it, and right now, I've got only my android on which I can work. So, I'll possibly try it out by Monday. Also, can you explain me more about it? I'm confused where to add directory names. Yes sure it's `sed` , but what if I want to add more than 3 paths/names? How do I proceed?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly. Don't hesitate to ask if you have any doubt or question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/system/bin/sh -xv

Z=/absolute/path/to/WorkingDir
T=320
F=480 # ?
I=540 # ?
D=dark
L=light
P=play # ?

cd $Z

for dir in $Z*/*/; do

    if [ -d $Z/$T/$D ] && [ ! -f $T$D.zip ]; then
        zip -0rq $T$D.zip $dir;            
    elif [ -d $Z/$T/$L ] && [ ! -f $T$L.zip ]; then      # elif rules
        zip -0rq $T$L.zip $dir;
    # It's not very efficient to scale this up, but you could add more elif statements here.
    elif [ -d $Z/$F/$D ] && [ ! -f $F$D.zip]; then
        zip -0rq $F$D.zip $dir;
    # and so on..
    else
        exit
    fi;
done
```

I think this is all you need. Let me know if it needs any adjustments.

Comment: Thank you! But you forgot to change the directory after `if [conditions] ` it zipped whole directory! Also, can you tell me how to add more elif conditions? Because there exist paths like `320/play` `480/light` `540/dark` and so on.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer after reading your comment. Hopefully this can work for you

Comment: Yes that did work. But one little problem again. When I open the zip, it doesn't show me the files under `$Z/*/*/` directly. Instead it actually creates a path under it like `/absolute/path/to/WorkingDir/540/light/` and then shows the actual contents.